# SSRS report table including Averages

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a report that has some data in it with calculation data among regular rows. For example:

```
Name  |  Age  |  Salary

HR    |  35   |   $1300  
John  |  30   |   $1000  
Mark  |  40   |   $1600

Law   |  45   |   $1500  
Bill  |  40   |   $1000  
Sara  |  50   |   $2000
```

The idea is to group rows by a field and then add a row with average numbers for this group.

Is it possible? I also have 2 date parameters (start and end), so I need to  get all the records to SSRS and then filter them out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and very straight forward.

Create your report with the data rows, then create a group on the Department field. You can do this a few ways: right click on the detail rows and select `Add Group...` or drag the department field to the Row groups pane in the design window.

Add a row to the group by right clicking on the details group and choosing to add a total, before the details. In the new row, set your formula to be `=Avg(MyDataset!AgeFieldName.Value)`

Take a look at the [tutorials available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522859%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), especially the [Grouping and Totals section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)